Creating Flowchart using Tikz
My MWE for generating a flowchart using Tikz is:
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

% Define styles
\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30},
  process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

% Define nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {Start Process};
\node (data) [process, below of=start] {Collection};
\node (training) [process, below of=data, xshift=-3cm] {AA};
\node (testing) [process, below of=data, xshift=3cm] {BB};
\node (ml) [process, below of=training] {Model Employment};
\node (prediction) [process, below of=ml] {Data Predict};
\node (comparison) [process, below of=prediction] {Comparison};
\node (bestfit) [process, below of=comparison] {Best Value};
\node (end) [startstop, below of=bestfit] {End};
\node (validation) [process, right of=comparison, xshift=3cm] {Validation Data};

% Draw arrows
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (data);
\draw [arrow] (data) -- (training);
\draw [arrow] (data) -- (testing);
\draw [arrow] (training) -- (ml);
\draw [arrow] (testing) |- node[anchor=south] {Verify} (ml);
\draw [arrow] (ml) -- (prediction);
\draw [arrow] (prediction) -- (comparison);
\draw [arrow] (comparison) -- (bestfit);
\draw [arrow] (bestfit) -- (end);
\draw [arrow] (validation) -- (comparison);
\draw [arrow] (data) -- (validation);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



This provides me the following:

However, particular lines in my flowchart are overlapping and the output isn't what I am expecting to generate. The text 'Verify' also overlaps with the line on the right side.
The expected outcome I am willing to get is:

Any insights and help would be much appreciated.

Please note that \tikzstyle is deprecated. Have a look at \tikzset instead.

Look for -| and |- syntax ...

I have updated the code as suggested, however, still unable to generate the flow-chart. I am new to TikZ. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

I have updated the code as suggested, however, still unable to generate the flow-chart. I am new to TikZ. @MS-SPO

We try to guide you, i.e. show you fishing. // To simplify your task I suggest to tackle problems here in this order, reducing visual noise: 1) comment out all connections and get positions right. Try left of= at least once. 2) change shape of comparison. 3) Introduce the simple connections WITHOUT any label. 4) Introduce 1 intermediate point below collection, AND 2 via pos= statements below collection and model. 5) Use these 3 points to connect straight first, and next with -|. 6) For verify also pos and anchor=west, or north, as you like.

As Suggestion for your next flowchart: See just the centers of the boxes in the intended chart, and recognize the 3col x 7rows matrix. Use these matrix from tikz to introduce/place those 9 nodes. This releases you from the below of= burden on the expense of a few tabular like lines. The connections will be the same, i.e. nothing changes there.

Section 3 here: https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb39-1/tb121duck-tikz.pdf could help.

Thanks for all the help. I was able to generate the correct flow-chart!

Great. Feel free to post your solution as a self-answer (and accept it a few days later).

here it is
I added two libraries (calc and positioning)
I created an intermediate coordinate under Collection
I used the -| and |- plot commands for right angle plots.
I used ($(data.south)!0.5!(aa)$) which calculates a point between the data and aa nodes to start the plot to Validation
I used the ellipse command for the comparison node.
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows,positioning,calc}

% Define styles
\tikzset{
  startstop/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30},
  process/.style={rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=orange!30},
  arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

% Define nodes
\node (start) [startstop] {Start Process};
\node (data) [process, below of=start] {Collection};
\node (training) [process, below of=data, xshift=-3cm] {AA};
\node (testing) [process, below of=data, xshift=3cm] {BB};
\node (ml) [process, below of=training] {Model Employment};
\node (prediction) [process, below of=ml] {Data Predict};
\node (comparison) [process, below of=prediction,ellipse] {Comparison};
\node (bestfit) [process, below of=comparison] {Best Value};
\node (end) [startstop, below of=bestfit] {End};
\node (validation) [process, left=1cm of training] {Validation Data};

% Draw arrows
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (data);
\draw [arrow] (data) --++(0,-1cm)coordinate(aa)-| (training);
\draw [arrow] (data) -- (aa) -|(testing);
\draw [arrow] (training) -- (ml);
\draw [arrow] (testing) |- node[anchor=south] {Verify} (ml);
\draw [arrow] (ml) -- (prediction);
\draw [arrow] (prediction) -- (comparison);
\draw [arrow] (comparison) -- (bestfit);
\draw [arrow] (bestfit) -- (end);
\draw [arrow] (validation) |- (comparison);
\draw [arrow] ($(data.south)!0.5!(aa)$) -| (validation);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



Great  // Next time, try tikzlibrary arrows.meta and set >={Stealth} . May be, you like it, too.

If you know the trick \draw [arrow] (data) --++(0,-1cm)coordinate(aa)-| (training);, your last command can be replaced as \draw [arrow] (data.south) ++ (0,-0.25cm) -| (validation);. No calc library needed.

I know Tom but it allows you to always have a point in the middle.
